# Returning pointer to wchar_t from function

Tags: c++

Why this code doesn't work?

```
wchar_t path[300];
wchar_t *PathCreator(wchar_t *dir, wchar_t *fileName)
{
    int j = 0;
    while(j < 300)
    {
        path[j] = '\0';
        j++;
    }
    int i;
    i = 0;
    while(*dir != '*')
    {
        path[i] = *dir;
        i++;
        dir++;
    }
    wchar_t *t = fileName;  
    while(*t != '\0')
    {
        path[i] = *t;
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    path[i] = '\0';
    //std::wcout << path << std::endl;
    return path;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
    std::wcout << PathCreator(L"A",L"B");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore I don't know what the problem. When I'm try the same function with void retrning value it vorks great, but when i'm try to return pointer to array it's terminated.

Comment: You are comparing variables of type `wchar_t` with literals of type `char`. Add `L` prefix to the character literals. e.g. : `L'*'`

Comment: @Vsevywniy what do you mean by "but when i'm try to return pointer to array it's terminated"? does it crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is wrong, it doesn't check for the end of `dir`. So

```
while(*dir != '*' && *dir != '\0')
{
    path[i] = *dir;
    i++;
    dir++;
}
```

not

```
while(*dir != '*')
{
    path[i] = *dir;
    i++;
    dir++;
}
```